# Library not being extended in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm trying to extend the input library (CI 2.1.1), and when I call my custom save query function, its saying the function doesn't exist.

File: MY_Input.php, in the applications/libraries folder:_

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {
 var $CI;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

function save_query($query_array) {
    $this->CI->db->insert('ci_query', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));
 }
}
```

And in the controller I'm calling the function like this

```
$query_id = $this->input->save_query($query_array);
```

So what on earth am I doing wrong that it's giving me this error:_

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::save_query() in ....
```

Can't see why it's not working, I even checked the user guide and according to it I guess I'm doing it right. :/

Comment: I don't know about codeigniter, but I guess you'll need to register your class as the replacement of CI_Input somewhere, you can't expect it to just magically work.

Comment: I'd guess you've been looking at the documentation for 'Extending Native Libraries' - the Input class is a core class, so try looking at the documentation for ['Extending Core Class'](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: @Lefters , now that I put it in application/core folder on every page it says: Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\codeigniter-tests\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Comment: @Maerlyn, codeigniter does the magic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CI_Input` class is a core library (new thing in CI2.0.0). You will have to put your `MY_Input.php` file under `application/core/` to make the framework pick it up.

When in doubt, look for the original class under `system/core` or `system/libraries` and mirror it under `application/`.

Comment: now it says: Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\codeigniter-tests\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Comment: it says that on every page.... and when I dont get_instance() it says call to non member function Undefined property: MY_Input::$db and Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in the MY_Input.php

Comment: Probably because the Input class loads before the controller instantiated or even loaded. Since you are trying to access the controller instance in the input class's constructor it wont work. Try putting the get_instance() call into the `save_query()` method.

Comment: thanks that made it work! :D btw, what if I wanted to use it in many functions(the CI instance), do i have to put that line in every function :(, oh well... thanks anyways!

Comment: I guess could write soma magick `__get()` implementation that lazily initializes the variable on the first use, or if you can write a normal library instead of extending a base class that doesn't have this loading issue, but this kinda offtopic (-: